# Powershell select-object empty

Tags: powershell, select-object

I try to get `FolderPath` for Exchange Mailboxes like this:

```
get-mailbox | select Name,@{L="FoldePath";E={(Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $_.Name).folderpath}}
```

This gives me the following output:

```
Name       FoldePath
----       ---------
User01     {/Top of Information Store, /Calendar, /Contacts, /Delet...
User02     {/Top of Information Store, /Calendar, /Contacts, /Delet...
```

That's good, but when I try to get `FolderPath` for a single mailbox, it returns empty output.

```
get-mailbox User01 | select Name,@{L="FoldePath";E={(Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $_.Name).folderpath}}
```

```
Name        FoldePath
----        ---------
User01
```

Format-Table returns correct output:

```
get-mailbox User01 | ft Name,@{L="FoldePath";E={(Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $_.Name).folderpath}}
```

```
Name    FoldePath
----    ---------
User01  {/Top of Information Store, /Calendar, /Contacts, /Delet...
```

Can I get correct output with `Select-Object` cmdlet? What is the difference?